# min-height:100% not working in IE8 (and possibly other versions)

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a page composed of 3 sections, each having a height of 100% of the window / viewport. I found a way to do this that works in Chrome, Firefox (at least the newer versions) and Safari. It isn't working, however in IE8 (and possibly other versions as well).

Here's the test page: http://dev.manifold.ws/test3/

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>

    <section id="section1">
    </section>

    <section id="section2">
    </section>

    <section id="section3">
    </section>

</body>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#section1 {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#fc1b59;
}

#section2 {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#d5ea27;
}

#section3 {
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative;
    background:#0048ff;
}
```

Would anyone have a cross-browser solution to this? (At least the major newer browsers)
Thanks!

-Thom

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion: you have yet to accept a single answer on SO, with the first one being more than 6 months old. Please consider acknowledging the help others provide by marking some answers before asking more questions. You'll get much better help/feedback if others know you'll reward them for it.

Comment: What if you temporarily change `<section>`s to `<div>`s? To use HTML5 elements (almost perfectly) in older IEs you have to use http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ or http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Hi KP, you're absolutely right. I didn't realize I was suppose to click the check mark to accept an answer. I just accepted previous answers. I'm very thankful to all the help I've gotten. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hi biziclop, looks like changing <section> to <div> did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the IE javascript shiv for HTML5 and declare all HTML5 elements as BLOCK elements.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Consider using this reset CSS file as a base:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Hi Billy Moat, I'm sure your solution would work as well but I ended up simply changing <section> to <div> as @biziclop suggested and it did the trick. I will keep your solution in mind if I want to use HTML5 in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as long as you understand what was happening? SECTION is a new HTML5 element that won't display as a block level element in older browsers unless you tell it to. It's the same with otjer new TML5 elmenets such as footer, header, article, nav, aside figure etc :)

Comment: in adition to this, you might want to use a min-height hack for IE. Google "min-height fast hack" (from dustin diaz), that one works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, IE8 doesn't know `<section>` (HTML5) tag, you need to add some JS :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

([source](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/))

Second, you need to specify IE8 that `<section>` is a block :

```
section {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUYDS/1/)